# Download to Excel from web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, export-to-excel

In my web app i have a excel icon which when user clicks it will download the tab seperated data into excel.

Below is the code with which i accomplished it.

**HTML code:**

```
<a id="lol" href="#" target=_blank download=file1.tsv >EXCEL </a>
```

**Javascript code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
 var sdf = "http://getTabSeperatedData.com";
 $('#lol').attr("href",sdf);
});
```

http://getTabSeperatedData.com will provide me the tab seperated data.

Now I have two problems.

1) I want to set the column width to a default value. is there any way i can do that.
   Reason: first column is always lengthy. So by default i want to set it to large width

2) i will have multiple tables which i want to download to different tabs in same excel sheet.

Will HTML5 support any of those functionalities. Any example having that feature will be much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Tab-separated value file do not contain formatting information. You won't be able to set column widths or any other formats in a TSV file.

Similarly, there's no structural information in a TSV file beyond basic lines and fields. You can't separate sections to go to different worksheets.

However, you could generate an Excel spreadsheet directly and download that. This will allow you to include column widths, worksheets and other Excel facilities. Take a look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)